# How handle style chart click event on nvd3

Tags: nvd3.js

I want to remove stream style (state ? ("Stream", "Stacked" and "Expanded")) on stacked area chart and use this code :

```
 d3.selectAll("g.nv-series")
        .filter(function() {
            return d3.select(this).select("text").text() == "Stream";
        })
        .remove();
```

But it works only the first time. 
I tryed to handle events on chart because i want to refresh rendering of chart but it didn't work for the styles click. It works only for the legend click.

```
chart.legend.dispatch.on('legendClick', function(e){
     console.log('legend was clicked', 'no namespace.');
});
```

How i can i handle click on style event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- setter

`chart.style('stream');`

- getter

`chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) {
    console.log(e); //e.style holds the current style
});`

List of available styles can be found here https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/stackedArea.js#L299-L318

I also had hard time with this issue so I hope this would help you.
Cheers!